# Count numbers in a string and add them to array

Tags: arrays, string

I have a string that a user inputs through Console.ReadLine() e.g. "140 150 64 49" (separated only with spaces) and I want to add those numbers to an array. What is the best way to do it. I'm kinda new to programming so I'm a bit lost. Google didn't help either.

Comment: You could loop through each single character and try to convert it to a number. If the conversion succeeds, it means that it's a number.

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: He is using C#, as we can notice from the use of ReadLine()

Comment: I'm using C#. Problem is I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saying you're using Console.ReadLine(), I assume you use C#.

you can use this:

```
        int counter = 0;
        int[] array = new int[200]; // choose some size
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        int indexOfNextSpace;
        while ((indexOfNextSpace = s.IndexOf(' ')) > -1)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, indexOfNextSpace));
            array[counter] = num;
            counter++;
            s = s.Substring(indexOfNextSpace + 1);
        }
```

if you're not sure about valid input, try surrounding with try\catch, or use int.TryParse instead of int.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
int num;
int[] result = new int[] { };

string input = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (string str in input.Split(' '))
{
    if (int.TryParse(str, out num))
    {
        ints.Add(num);
    }
}

result = ints.ToArray();

foreach (int i in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

It uses a List then convert it to array. Note that items are validated, so only ints are added.

This will produce the following output:

```
123 456 dsf def 1

123
456
1
```